# Performance Issues with SharpDX and D3DImage

Tags: c#, wpf, directx, dispatcher, sharpdx

I have a control that uses D3DImage to host a SharpDX DirectX9 surface and allows use to pan, zoom, and interact with world objects and the result is really awesome.  Performance is actually an amazing consistent 60fps EXCEPT when the window is minimized and brought back up or the user locks and then unlocks the screen.  When the window regains focus the fps drop to about 25-30fps.  I can "fix" the issue by unloading and loading the control back into its container and then BOOM, 60fps.

I call the main render function using a DispatcherTimer set at 10ms.  Before, I was using the CompositionTarget.Rendering event but performance wasn't as good as using the DispatcherTimer.  I fairly certain that I'm handling lost resources correctly.  Any ideas about these missing frames per second?

EDIT:  [I am having this same exact problem](http://www.gamedev.net/topic/613659-c-dx9-slow-down-after-losing-window-focus/).  Unfortunately, doing an automatic device reset doesn't fix the issue but if I have a button that executes the same reset method then my fps goes back to normal.

Answer (score 2):

Locking / Unlocking the screen causes a device lost. But you probably know that.

Anyway I use D3DImage in WPF as well. My performance problems ended when I called

```
D3DImage.SetBackBuffer(D3DResourceType.IDirect3DSurface9, IntPtr.Zero)
```

on each device lost. I used to have responsiveness issues after a device lost until I realized WPF was still holding a reference to a texture. Of course you should later re-set the backbuffer when you have an updated texture.

Although it is unclear what exactly is going wrong behind the scenes, it is clear that D3DImage keeps a refcount to your texture, which can prohibit a successful recovery in the case of a device lost. In my case, we simply had no updates.

Sorry for the anectodal answer... But until a real D3DImage expert enters the room, it's better than nothing.

P.S. I am using SlimDX but I don't think it matters... For all that I know SharpDX is a fork of SlimDX.

Comment: I'm using DeviceEx, no textures, and all my resources are being handled just fine.  I don't set the backbuffer to IntPtr.Zero when IsFrontBufferAvailable changed to false because I've never received the event from false to true if I do that.  I'm inclined to believe that this is some weird WPF thing that I don't know about.  The sluggishness can come from minimizing the window and back (I have no code attached to visibility or anything).  Also performance can back if I simply give another application focus for a bit and then come back to my active app.

Answer (score 0):

There's an overload to `SetBackBuffer` that takes an additional `Boolean` flag:

> [D3DImage.SetBackBuffer(D3DResourceType, IntPtr, Boolean)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh140978(v=vs.110).aspx)
>
> When you call the **SetBackBuffer**(D3DResourceType, IntPtr) overload, or call the SetBackBuffer(D3DResourceType, IntPtr, Boolean) overload with the **enableSoftwareFallback** parameter set to false, the  [WPF] rendering system releases its reference to the back buffer when the front buffer becomes unavailable and nothing is displayed.

I'm no expert either, but I would guess that this is what's happening; Because you didn't set that flag to 'true', WPF is calling `Release()` on what happens to be the last COM ref count for your D3D surface as soon as it exits the lock. This would seem to require that you be maintaining an additional ref count of your own.

For one thing, I've noticed that, even after getting your "used" surface "back" from a WPF lock/unlock round-trip, you need to still **not release it** until your *next* surface takes its place (i.e. in a successful call to **d3dimg.SetBackBuffer**). Otherwise, you'll get flickering when the WPF window is dragged around the screen. Given that that's the only reliable method I've discovered for detecting when WPF is truly done with *your* buffer, it does seem pointless for WPF to be concerned with AddRef'ing or Release'ing it.

What's generally confusing with `D3DImage` is that the `IDirect3DDevice9` that's running WPF is not really associated with the `IDirect3DDevice9` that generated the surface you're putting forth as a back buffer... for WPF. The whole `Lock/Unlock` business is presumably for WPF's benefit, and has nothing to do with your own (possibly lockable?) `IDirect3DSurface9` rendertarget's survival.

---

**Beware!**
If using `D3DImage.TryLock`, beware of its, um... shall we say, *unconventional* semantics: You must call `Unlock` even in the case where `TryLock` returns **false**. For more information, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/39581727/147511.